# Material UI v5 - Tabs style override

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to override MuiTabs style - more specifically flexContainer (.MuiTabs-flexContainer). First, can someone explain me what exactly represent these ".css-heg063" in front of the selector? Is this sth from styled-componentes incorporated with MUI or? Before upgrading MUI version I haven't seen those. Second, in my theme.ts file I want my content to flex-end but this doesn't apply to my app at all. What is wrong with my code?

[image: picture01]

[image: picture02]

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

You cannot simply use flex box properties because these will cause misplacement of the active-indicator.

It can be achieved with simple margin property

```
margin-left: 'auto';
```

> Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-y1278?file=/demo.js

**Long Answer:**

Just think of `.css-heg063` as a code generated by your parser (`babel` in most cases) to uniquely identify the CSS you wrote in different chunks(files, modules or pre-processors).

For Example: if you have same css-selector name written in two different files with different css properties. you want to use both at different places. Parser prepends a unique ID/hash/number to the classname to identify without any extra developer effort.

Comment: In previos version of MUI when I wrote:
MuiTabs: {
flexContainer:{
justifyContent:"flex-end",
},
}
it worked perfectly fine..

Comment: You are absolutely right, because at that time the the indicator overlay was under the flex container but now its not in.
For ideal case, they should provide a align property to the Tabs component to control the base alignment of the childs]

Comment: Also making margin auto is the correct thing to do because, root component is taking full width  and its not a flex-box as well so you have to cut-short the white space on left by using margin-left: "auto";